# Assotiate with URL protocol

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

In our desktop app we associate it with URL protocol using the registry. 
We write to this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes
```

For example, to associate our app with `magnet:` links we use the following code:

```
    QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Classes", QSettings::NativeFormat);    
    settings.setValue("magnet/Default", "URL:Magnet link");
    settings.setValue("magnet/Content Type", "application/x-magnet");
    settings.setValue("magnet/URL Protocol", "");
    settings.setValue("magnet/DefaultIcon/Default", QDir::toNativeSeparators(icon_str));
    settings.setValue("magnet/shell/Default", "open");
    settings.setValue("magnet/shell/open/command/Default", QDir::toNativeSeparators(command_str));
```

Once we execute this code, browsers are able to launch our app when the user clicks on a `magnet:` link.

Is this possible for our app being converted using `Desktop App Converter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted desktop-bridge apps declare their protocol association in the appxmanifest, not the registry:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#protocol